# Hot reloading doesn't work on a react-native app with react-router-native and redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-router, react-router-redux, hot-module-replacement

I'm starting with react native and I have a little experience with React, Because of that I want to use `redux`, `react-router`, and `react-router-redux`, which I have used in the past for a web React app.

All those packages can be used in react-native, except for react-router, the closest I could find is `react-router-native` which seems to work much like the browser version. So far so good, I made a quick and dirty app to test the router, redux, etc.

But I'm having some issues I can't figure out how to solve or debug: When changing the visuals like the text or some styles, the HMR seems to work fine, applying the changes in real time, but when I change some other module/file, like the container element (where the redux connect() function is called) or some code on the reducers, the HMR doesn't change anything and I have to reload all the app to see the changes.

Here is my code: https://github.com/DenJohX/test-react-router-native It basically just changes the color of some text by toggling a variable in the redux store. Sorry for just linking it but I think its better to show you all the folders and project structure, maybe I'd just goofed something in there or didn't use the correct folder structure.

I'm using https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger to debug the app, and by the console messages, the HMR does run and patches something but without affecting the current loaded code.

To test the problem, try to edit the colors in `src/screens/pageOneContainer.js`, the HMR should change the code, re-render the screen, and show the new colors, but they just stays the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the problem with reloading the app?

Comment: reloading the app really slows down development, say you have a scene you have to navigate through 5 or 6 buttons and forms before reaching it. You dont want that for each small code change